# How to prevent a statement from breaking the control flow in Java

Tags: java, error-handling, structure

I have a statement that I think it breaks the control flow of my code. The statement is `s.executeBatch();` `s` is an instance of `java.sql.Statement`.

```java
else if (event.getSource()==btnSave)
{
    btnAdd.doClick();
    int a[]=s.executeBatch(); 
    System.out.println ("dddddd");
    btnRefresh.doClick(); 
    con.commit(); 
    s.clearBatch();
}
```

Everything after this `s.executeBatch();`) is not executed if I comment it in, the `doClick();`  and  `System.out.println` statements are executed.

This is the information included in Oracle's docs on `executeBatch()':

> `executeBatch()` Submits a batch of commands to the database for
>   execution and if all commands execute successfully, returns an array
>   of update counts.

Comment: the core problem (as described in the question title) has not solved yet & i did not get an answer for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the problematic statement in a try catch block and handle the exception gracefully.

Unhandled exception will make the control to return to the calling method for exception handling. Catching an exception will give you control to do the corrective actions and if logical then proceed with rest of the code.

Put try/catch around your problematic statement s.executeBatch(), like this:

```
 else if (event.getSource()==btnSave)
    {
        btnAdd.doClick();
        int a[];
        try {
            a=s.executeBatch(); System.out.println ("dddddd");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.prointln("Exception happened");
        }
            btnRefresh.doClick(); 
         con.commit(); 
        s.clearBatch();
    }
```

Comment: Not exactly a textbook examlpe of "graceful" exceeption handling :) The transaction should be rolled back in the catch, and `doClick` and other stuff may go to `finally`,.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik all good points, i just wanted to address to use try catch around a statement which may encounter an exception.

Comment: thank you @Oliver F., you are awesome
the exception has really occurred :)
see this screenshot:
http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/341/inkb.jpg
i don't know actually what is the problem with my code 
i will attach the code for you (its simple & short)
please can you take a look at my code & help me ...I'm a beginner 

here is the code:
http://goo.gl/uJFZga

for admins & reviewers
I wish you forgive me on any mistake in the use of the site
This is my first Post
Thank you

Comment: @Juned Ahsan
see my comment

Comment: Juned Ahsan your post helped me a lot